# Can additive inverse by itself define binary subtraction?

Tags: real-numbers, model-theory

Consider the two structures $(\mathbb{R};f)$ and $(\mathbb{R};-)$, where $f$ represents additive inverse, and $-$ represents binary subtraction. Certainly, $f$ can be defined from $-$. Can $-$ be defined by $f$? I don't think it can, but I want a formal proof that no possible definition works.

Edit: It is very clear to me that $-$ can't be expressed by a term in $f$, but I am wondering if the graph of $-$ can be defined by a first-order formula in $f$.

Comment: Do you mean without having a $+$?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "define"?

Comment: In any case, for any reasonable notion of "define", the answer will be no, since $(\mathbb{R};f)$ has automorphisms that do not preserve $-$ (you should be able to find some for yourself).

Comment: I am not sure that "$f$ can be defined from $-$" either. (Unless you specify "definable with parameters".) In fact, $-$ is translation invariant, $f$ is not.

Comment: @PrimoPetri We have that $x - y = z$ implies $(x+5) - (y+5) = z$ (which is probably what you mean), but $(x+5) - (y+5) \neq z + 5$. So translation is not an automorphism. In fact, $f$ is $0$-definable in $(\mathbb{R}; -)$, because $0$ is $0$-definable in that structure (that's a lot of $0$s, but hopefully it's clear which means what).

Comment: @PrimoPetri The term $(x-x)-x$ defines $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To move this off the unanswered queue, I'll expand Eric Wofsey's comment into an answer:*

Definable structure is always preserved by automorphisms. To show that subtraction can't be defined from inversion alone, we just need to find some permutation of $\mathbb{R}$ respecting inversion but not respecting subtraction. One example which I quite like is the function $$b(x)=\begin{cases}
x & \mbox{ if } x\in\mathbb{Q},\\
f(x) & \mbox{ if } x\not\in\mathbb{Q}.\\
\end{cases}$$ To see that $b$ does not in fact preserve subtraction just note that e.g. $b(\pi-(\pi-1))=b(1)=1$ but $b(\pi)-b(\pi-1)=-\pi-(1-\pi)-1$.

There are two quick notes worth making at this point:

- First, the above analysis has very little to do with first-order logic. Isomorphism invariance of satisfaction, and consequently automorphism invariance of definability, is (almost always) one of the defining criteria for something to be a logic in the first place. So really what the above shows is that inversion can't define subtraction in *any* logical system.
- Second, note that inversion is really *combinatorial* rather than *algebraic* when taken on its own: the structure $(\mathbb{R};f)$ is better thought of as just a set equipped with an equivalence relation, namely $\vert x\vert=\vert y\vert$, which partitions it into continuum-many pairs and one singleton. Thought of this way it's clear that we shouldn't expect any expressive power (and moreover this motivates non-*interpretability*, rather than mere non-*definability*, results).